# How to update my CameraManager to latest version?

Tags: android, camera

I have a camera manager class, which is used for capture image of selected area. I can get a picture image with in a rect, which is selected by user.
It runs well in API version 19. 
But I can't use it in latest version.
How can I update it?
These are my current work.

```
/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraManager extends SurfaceView  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public Camera getCamera() {
        return mCamera;
    }

    /**
     * A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object.
     */
    public Camera getCameraInstance(int nIdx) {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(nIdx); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You have not camera or your camera is used in other app.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        // Create an instance of Camera
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
                Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
                if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                    mCamera = getCameraInstance(i);
                }
            }
        }
        if (mCamera == null)
            return;
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        Point screenResolution = new Point(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        Point cameraResolution = findBestPreviewSizeValue(parameters, screenResolution);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(cameraResolution.x, cameraResolution.y);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }
    private static final int MIN_PREVIEW_PIXELS = 470 * 320; // normal screen
    private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_PIXELS = 800 * 600; // more than large/HD screen

    private Point findBestPreviewSizeValue(Camera.Parameters parameters, Point screenResolution) {

        // Sort by size, descending
        List<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes = new ArrayList<Camera.Size>(parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes());
        Collections.sort(supportedPreviewSizes, new Comparator<Camera.Size>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Camera.Size a, Camera.Size b) {
                int aPixels = a.height * a.width;
                int bPixels = b.height * b.width;
                if (bPixels < aPixels) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (bPixels > aPixels) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        });

        if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.INFO)) {
            StringBuilder previewSizesString = new StringBuilder();
            for (Camera.Size supportedPreviewSize : supportedPreviewSizes) {
                previewSizesString.append(supportedPreviewSize.width).append('x')
                        .append(supportedPreviewSize.height).append(' ');
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Supported preview sizes: " + previewSizesString);
        }

        Point bestSize = null;
        float screenAspectRatio = (float) screenResolution.x / (float) screenResolution.y;

        float diff = Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        for (Camera.Size supportedPreviewSize : supportedPreviewSizes) {
            int realWidth = supportedPreviewSize.width;
            int realHeight = supportedPreviewSize.height;
            int pixels = realWidth * realHeight;
            if (pixels < MIN_PREVIEW_PIXELS || pixels > MAX_PREVIEW_PIXELS) {
                continue;
            }
            boolean isCandidatePortrait = realWidth < realHeight;
            int maybeFlippedWidth = isCandidatePortrait ? realHeight : realWidth;
            int maybeFlippedHeight = isCandidatePortrait ? realWidth : realHeight;
            if (maybeFlippedWidth == screenResolution.x && maybeFlippedHeight == screenResolution.y) {
                Point exactPoint = new Point(realWidth, realHeight);
                Log.i(TAG, "Found preview size exactly matching screen size: " + exactPoint);
                return exactPoint;
            }
            float aspectRatio = (float) maybeFlippedWidth / (float) maybeFlippedHeight;
            float newDiff = Math.abs(aspectRatio - screenAspectRatio);
            if (newDiff < diff) {
                bestSize = new Point(realWidth, realHeight);
                diff = newDiff;
            }
        }

        if (bestSize == null) {
            Camera.Size defaultSize = parameters.getPreviewSize();
            bestSize = new Point(defaultSize.width, defaultSize.height);
            Log.i(TAG, "No suitable preview sizes, using default: " + bestSize);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Found best approximate preview size: " + bestSize);
        return bestSize;
    }


    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public CameraManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            openCamera();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
        releaseCamera();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null || mCamera == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private Rect framingRect;
    private static final int MIN_FRAME_WIDTH = 20; // originally 240
    private static final int MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT = 50; // originally 240
    private static final int MAX_FRAME_WIDTH = 800; // originally 480
    private static final int MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT = 1200; // originally 360

    public Rect getImageRect()
    {
        Point screenResolution = new Point(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        Camera.Size totalSize = mCamera.getParameters().getPictureSize();
        float fRatioX = (float) totalSize.height / (float) screenResolution.x;
        float fRatioY = (float) totalSize.width / (float) screenResolution.y;

        float fRatio = Math.max(fRatioX, fRatioY);

        Rect rcRes = new Rect(
                (int)(framingRect.left * fRatioX),
                (int)(framingRect.top * fRatioY),
                (int)(framingRect.right * fRatioX),
                (int)(framingRect.bottom * fRatioY) );
        return rcRes;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the framing rect which the UI should draw to show the user where to place the
     * barcode. This target helps with alignment as well as forces the user to hold the device
     * far enough away to ensure the image will be in focus.
     *
     * @return The rectangle to draw on screen in window coordinates.
     */
    public synchronized Rect getFramingRect() {
        if (framingRect == null) {
            if (mCamera == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Point screenResolution = new Point(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

            if (screenResolution == null) {
                // Called early, before init even finished
                return null;
            }
            int width = screenResolution.x * 3/5;
            if (width < MIN_FRAME_WIDTH) {
                width = MIN_FRAME_WIDTH;
            } else if (width > MAX_FRAME_WIDTH) {
                width = MAX_FRAME_WIDTH;
            }
            int height = screenResolution.y * 1/5;
            if (height < MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT) {
                height = MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT;
            } else if (height > MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT) {
                height = MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT;
            }
            int leftOffset = (screenResolution.x - width) / 2;
            int topOffset = (screenResolution.y - height) / 2;
            framingRect = new Rect(leftOffset, topOffset, leftOffset + width, topOffset + height);
        }
        return framingRect;
    }

    /**
     * Changes the size of the framing rect.
     *
     * @param deltaWidth Number of pixels to adjust the width
     * @param deltaHeight Number of pixels to adjust the height
     */
    public synchronized void adjustFramingRect(int deltaWidth, int deltaHeight) {
        Point screenResolution = new Point(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

        // Set maximum and minimum sizes
        if ((framingRect.width() + deltaWidth > screenResolution.x - 4) || (framingRect.width() + deltaWidth < 50)) {
            deltaWidth = 0;
        }
        if ((framingRect.height() + deltaHeight > screenResolution.y - 4) || (framingRect.height() + deltaHeight < 50)) {
            deltaHeight = 0;
        }

        int newWidth = framingRect.width() + deltaWidth;
        int newHeight = framingRect.height() + deltaHeight;
        int leftOffset = (screenResolution.x - newWidth) / 2;
        int topOffset = (screenResolution.y - newHeight) / 2;
        framingRect = new Rect(leftOffset, topOffset, leftOffset + newWidth, topOffset + newHeight);
    }
}
```

I want to update it to camera2.
Is there a way to use these code in camera2?

Comment: have a look my answer

Answer (score 1):

The cmaera 1 api still works on API19, its just no longer recommended.  Your problem is probably because I don't see you requesting runtime permissions here.

If you really want to port it to camera2 it shouldn't be too difficult, but you'll be rewriting the entire class, and it probably isn't your problem.